# If I store a value in user default and if I close and run my app can I get my previous data along with new one?

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

When I am saving my username and score of a user in user defaults dictionary format for the first time it is saving but when I close and again run the app, previous data is being replaced by new one in dictionary.

How to append data to dictionary or how to store all users information while running the app multiple times?

```
var jo : [NSObject : AnyObject] = [
    uname:speed
] 
userDefaults.setObject(jo, forKey: akey)
var isOk = userDefaults.synchronize()
if let data0 = userDefaults.dictionaryForKey(akey) {
    println(data0)
} else {
    println("not set")
}
```

It is setting value for first time.

When I close and again run and give the file the dictionary is taking the new value replacing old but I want to add old value to new value.

Comment: Do you want to add a value to the dictionary or do you want to add another dictionary for the same key?

Comment: I want to add another key-value pair to dictionary like second username and his speed

Comment: i want to add another key:value pair to same dictionary...thank you

Comment: Does uname contain a string or some other type of value?

Comment: username string and speed integer

Comment: Its better to have a CSV string to save the data and next time just fetch the string append in the same string and save it.